# Discord.py bot TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a section of my Discord.py bot that creates some roles with colours that people can assign. When I try to run this I get the error shown in the question title.

```
# Imports

import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


# Variables

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">")
colours = ["Mint","Green","Blue","Pink","Purple","Yellow","Red","Black","White","Gold","Aqua"]
colourshex = ["1abc9c","2ecc71","3498db","e91e63","9b59b6","f1c40f","e74c3c","080808","ffffff","ffa800","00e5ff"]

# Enable


@client.event
async def on_ready():
print("Welcome to my bot")


# Module commands
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith(">module"):
        split = message.content.split(" ")
        if split[1].lower() == "colour":
            if split[2].lower() == "on":
                for x in range(0, len(colours)-1):
                    colourx = "Colour-%s" % colours[x]
                    colourxh = colourshex[x]
                    colourful = colourx + " " + colourxh
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, colourful)
                    await client.create_role(message.server, name=colourx)
                    await client.edit_role(server=message.server, role=discord.Role(colourx), colour=discord.Colour(colourxh))
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: It also might be easier to use a dictionary for colors and their hex values rather than two separate lists

Answer (score 0):

`Bot` is a subclass of `Client`.  You don't need to create both. You can also assign the role a color when you create it.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">")

colours = ["Mint","Green","Blue","Pink","Purple","Yellow","Red","Black","White","Gold","Aqua"]
colourshex = ["1abc9c","2ecc71","3498db","e91e63","9b59b6","f1c40f","e74c3c","080808","ffffff","ffa800","00e5ff"]

colourdict = dict(zip(colours, colourshex))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def colours(ctx):
    for name, hex in colourdict.items():
        await bot.say("Colour-{} {}".format(name, hex))
        await bot.create_role(ctx.message.server, name=name, colour=discord.Colour(hex))

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

You would invoke the above with `>colours`